# To make html element to display in a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a html page which contain an active X control. The html code is:

```
<div class="esv">
    <h2>John 3:16 <object class="audio" data=
    "http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016" height="12"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="40">
        <param name="movie" value=
        "http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    </object></h2>

    <div class="esv-text">
        <h3 id="p43003016.01-1">For God So Loved the World</h3>

        <p id="p43003016.07-1"><span class="verse-num woc" id=
        "v43003016-1">16&nbsp;</span><span class="woc">“For God so loved the
        world,<span class="footnote">&nbsp; <a href="#f1" id="b1" title=
        "Or 'For this is how God loved the world'">[1]</a></span> that he gave
        his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have
        eternal life.</span> (<a class="copyright" href=
        "http://www.esv.org">ESV</a>)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footnotes">
        <h3>Footnotes</h3>

        <p><span class="footnote"><a href="#b1" id="f1">[1]</a></span>
        <span class="footnote-ref">3:16</span> Or <em>For this is how God loved
        the world</em></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display it in a dialog which is likely as the image:
[image: test]

So I select jquery-ui to implement it. The code:

```
 $('#btn1').click(myFunction);
 $('#res1').dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     resizable: false,
     position: 'center',
     stack: true,
     height: 'auto',
     width: 'auto',
     modal: true
 });

 function myFunction() {
     var s = "<div class="esv"><h2>John 3:16 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  data="http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016" width="40" height="12" class="audio"><param name="movie" value="http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object></h2>
  <div class="esv-text"><h3 id="p43003016.01-1">For God So Loved the World</h3>
  <p id="p43003016.07-1"><span class="verse-num woc" id="v43003016-1">16&nbsp;</span><span class="woc">&#8220;For God so loved the world,<span class="footnote">&nbsp;<a href="#f1" id="b1" title="Or 'For this is how God loved the world'">[1]</a></span> that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.</span>  (<a href="http://www.esv.org" class="copyright">ESV</a>)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footnotes">
    <h3>Footnotes</h3>
    <p><span class="footnote"><a href="#b1" id="f1">[1]</a></span> <span class="footnote-ref">3:16</span> Or <em>For this is how God loved the world</em>
   </p>
   </div>
 </div>";
     $('#res1').html(s).dialog('open');
 }
```

It is not working. The demo is at [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/KK3V2/3/)

Comment: It's not valid code, what do you expect?

Comment: Seems like you have quotes issue: `var s = "<div class="esv"><h2>John 3` this will not work unless you qoute `esv` as `'esv'`

Comment: Do you mean double quotes? This is from a service response, I could not change it.

Comment: 1. Your quotes. You need to fix em.
2. set `autoOpen : false` in the dialog init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that the html fed to the dialog is valid, i.e. no quotes clashing with each other. Something that in principle looks like this:

```
 $('#btn1').click(myFunction);
 $('#res1').dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     resizable: false,
     position: 'center',
     stack: true,
     height: 'auto',
     width: 'auto',
     modal: true
 });

 function myFunction() {
     var htmlString = 'foo';
     $('#res1').html(htmlString).dialog('open');
 }
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KK3V2/5/) for a working example.

Comment: Do I have a chance to change my data to valid one? It is from a web service. I defined var s= "blahblah"; I mean to make s being valid.

Comment: If you control the webservice, you can clean up it's output? If not, you can take whatever HTML it returns and parse it to correctly escape all the single and double quotes.

Comment: Is there other way to do it? I have no control to the data. It comes an external web service. Can we use windows.open(url) rather than dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your example and have found a few errors.

First, anytime you need to insert a quote inside of a string you need to use the escape character . (i.e. \" will be stored in the string as "). Second I moved the function to be inside of the click event. Please review the code below.

Hope this helps.

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
         var s = "<div class=\"esv\"><h2>John 3:16 <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"  data=\"http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016\" width=\"40\" height=\"12\" class=\"audio\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016\" /><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\" /></object></h2><div class=\"esv-text\"><h3 id=\"p43003016.01-1\">For God So Loved the World</h3><p id=\"p43003016.07-1\"><span class=\"verse-num woc\" id=\"v43003016-1\">16&nbsp;</span><span class=\"woc\">&#8220;For God so loved the world,<span class=\"footnote\">&nbsp;<a href=\"#f1\" id=\"b1\" title=\"Or 'For this is how God loved the world'\">[1]</a></span> that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.</span>  (<a href=\"http://www.esv.org\" class=\"copyright\">ESV</a>)</p></div><div class=\"footnotes\"><h3>Footnotes</h3><p><span class=\"footnote\"><a href=\"#b1\" id=\"f1\">[1]</a></span> <span class=\"footnote-ref\">3:16</span> Or <em>For this is how God loved the world</em></p></div></div>";

 $('#res1').html(s).dialog('open');
});
$('#res1').dialog({
             autoOpen: true, resizable: false, position: 'center',
             stack: true, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', modal: true
         });
```